# How can a single downvote or upvote change the score of an answer by two not by one?

Tags: support

How can a single downvote or upvote change the score of an answer by two not by one?

I just saw that happen.

Answer (score 1):

It can't.

Someone voted while you where looking at the post.

The score is not continuously updated on your screen, but only when you refresh the page (and, IIRC, voting refreshes that part of the page).

Comment: Hmm.  It seems odd that when I reversed my vote and then reversed it again the same thing happened again.  Well, it's not terribly important to me, just curious.  And I didn't refresh the page in between votes.  Anyway so long as I'm reassured that every vote only counts with a weight of one, that's all I really want to know, thanks.

Comment: @quietflyer perhaps the second voter noticed and did the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think what may have happened is that I was toggling between an upvote and a downvote, and the difference between an upvote and a downvote is 2 not 1.  Kind of a dumb mistake on my part; I didn't realize that the way to simply retract an upvote is to hit the up arrow AGAIN, not to hit the down arrow.  Highly related to this question - [Please help me better understand how upvoting/ downvoting works](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3699/please-help-me-better-understand-how-upvoting-downvoting-works)  - I finally understand now, sorry about that.  If I ever see the vote score change by two the FIRST time I ever push an up or down arrow for a given question or answer, then I'll know something more complicated is going on but as of now I'm guessing that's not the case.